# Opening or activating workbook in Excel from VBS

Tags: excel, vbscript, com

I am writing a small VBScript to do the following:

1. Check if Excel is open; if not open it.
2. If Excel is open, check if a specific workbook is open.
3. If workbook is open, make it active; if not, open it.

So far I have been able to write the following code:

```
ExcelFileName = "....xlsx"

On Error Resume Next
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
IF Err Then
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
    WScript.Echo "Workbook not open (Excel is not running)."
    Else
    WScript.Echo Err.Description & " (0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & ")"
    End If
    WScript.Quit 1
End If
On Error Goto 0

Set wb = Nothing
For Each obj In xl.Workbooks
    If obj.Name = ExcelFileName Then
    Set wb=obj
    xl.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Save
    Exit For
    End If
Next

If wb Is Nothing Then
    xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\...")
End If

Set xl = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
```

But if Excel is not already open, it silently fails to open a new instance.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong when the script tries to open Excel?

Comment: At the moment Excel is not starting. I am using `GetObject(, "Excel.Application")`, which is why it is trying to attach to an existing Excel instance. If there is none (meaning Excel is closed) I want it to open Excel. I am sorry if I am not making myself very clear, it is my first time trying to code something.

Comment: Do you get any error, or does it just stay closed?

Comment: It just stays closed.

Comment: `GetObject` only gets an existing instance (if there is an object to *Get*). You need to `CreateObject` (create a new instance) if that fails. There have to be many examples of doing that here already. Did you search for them? I found an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12312566/62576) in the *Related* list to the right of this very question. ====>>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetObject behaves normally in giving you a running instance of Excel or causing an error. In case you get an error (Excel not running), use CreateObject to create a new instance of Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Use GetObject to open the file.

```
set wb = GetObject("c:\folder\excel.xls")
```

COM will work out what needs to be done. That one line is all you need for your three requirements.

This is the guts of what VB asks COM to do when using GetObject with a filename.

> **BindMoniker**
>
> Locates an object by means of its moniker, activates the object if it is inactive, and retrieves a pointer to the specified interface on that object.
>
> HRESULT BindMoniker(
>      LPMONIKER pmk,
>      DWORD grfOpt,
>      REFIID iidResult,
>      LPVOID FAR * ppvResult
>   );

Comment: I like the getobject for set wb, but then your problem becomes you don't know/have the parent application - and then have to get that.  Right?  I tried to create an excel application object, and then set wb using your GetObject method.  Then I tried to call applicationobject.run "openedworkbookname!macroname"  and the error I got was very interesting.  "sorry, we can't find c:\users\john\DOCUMENTS\...", when that wasn't even the path of the wb...